# command Phase swift execution error while i try to run my project in my device

Tags: swift4.1.5, xcode10beta3

Hai When i tried to run my code in my device i got the below

error./usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 13A01D0D81E2B38716BB9676A4AC64A9D4D91318  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/logesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Life_Project_Mobile-cmnrembpazemptgifdkxwudlutjp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Life Project Mobile.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework' /Users/logesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Life_Project_Mobile-cmnrembpazemptgifdkxwudlutjp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Life Project Mobile.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework: errSecInternalComponent

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Ios 11.4
Xcode 10.3 beta

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: See the answer here if this is still a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code