# Xcode fails building archive "fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything Illegal version"

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 10.2, when I build a project to run on the Simulator, it works just fine.  But when I click Product -> Archive, it fails with the unhelpful message

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything
Illegal version:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

What is the actual problem here?  I've tried [the lock & unlock trick with Keychain Access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383349/1789466), deleting the DerivedData folder, and restarting the computer, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in Build Phases I had a Run Script which was calling `git describe` to generate a version number, and that was raising the error message "fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything".

When I deleted the Run Script's call to `git describe`, it worked fine.