# Xcode 11.1 -no identity found Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode

My project was working just fine. Last night I successfully uploaded a binary to AppStoreConnect. All of a sudden when I go to build my project I get this error:

> Code Signing
>   /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImStuck-...../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ImStuck.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
>   with Identity iPhone Developer: Lance Samaria (52Q24UJ38T)
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign D0519CCxxxxxxxxxx 
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImStuck-...../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ImStuck.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
>   D0519CCxxxxxxxxxx: no identity found
>   Command PhaseScriptExecution
>   failed with a nonzero exit code

I cleaned derived data and then I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383349/4833705) and it didn't work.

It saying some number is missing:

```
D0519CCxxxxxxxxxx: no identity found
```

In the pic below the red bar is where the number is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I went to `Xcode` > `blue project icon` > `Signing & Capabilites` and unchecked `Automatically manage signing` then checked it again to turn it back on
2. I went my developer account then went to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` > `Certificates` > clicked each item then on the `Download Your Certificate` page I choose `Download`.
3. Once they downloaded I double clicked each one inside the downloads folder.
4. I found my original `p12 certificates` and `keys` then double clicked.
5. I went `Xcode` > `Preferences` > Choose my `Team` id then selected both `Download Manual Profiles` and `Manage Certificates`.
6. I went to `Xcode` > `blue project icon` > `Signing & Capabilites` and unchecked `Automatically manage signing` then checked it again to turn it back on
7. From there I closed the project, quit Xcode, and restarted my computer, restarted Xcode and pressed Build.

After everything booted back up the error went away.