# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ipa

I am trying to build an `archive` for my `flutter` app on `Xcode`, bt I do not know why I kept getting this error.

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have my project migrated using the [manual migration guildlines](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration) for the Xcode 11.4 version. My project runs well on the `simulator` though but I cannot build the `.ipa` archive file.

**Logs**

```
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-acigcqmznpynacbcdnfflfigyoxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Kashbase .app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: errSecInternalComponent
Non-fat binary /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-acigcqmznpynacbcdnfflfigyoxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Kashbase .app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is not armv7. Running lipo -info:
Non-fat file: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-acigcqmznpynacbcdnfflfigyoxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Kashbase .app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is architecture: x86_64
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you add the build log? Did you try to delete the DerivedData folder and building again?

Comment: just added my logs. please review. And yes, I have deleted DerivedData folder severally.

Comment: are you sure you did the migration step by step? it looks like you try to archive with App.framework for simulators, that looks like you are missing the `Thin Binary` step, try to check it and verify you add it after `Embedded Frameworks` section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

Go to

1. *Keychain Access* -> *Right-click on login* -> *Lock & unlock again*
2. *Xcode* -> *Clean Xcode project* -> *Make build again*

> *[Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/en-ph/guide/keychain-access/kyca1083/mac)*
> is a program in your Mac in Utilities. Cmd Tab keychain Access to find
> it.

You can also try other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) if the workaround mentioned above is not working.