# rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, rsync

[image]

I tried to connect flutter project to my iPhone, but suddenly this error showed up after adding Google AdMob. I've already tried keychain solution([Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)), `pod deintegrate`, `pod clean`, `pod install` . Also I changed project configurations variously, but it didn't work.

```
Build target Runner
Project Runner | Configuration Debug | Destination Ryan's iPhone | SDK iOS 13.6`
Run custom shell script 'Thin Binary' 0.1 seconds`
```

```
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/\#341\#204\#213\#341\#205\#265\#341\#204\#207\#341\#205\#265\#341\#206\#253\#341\#204\#202\#341\#205\#241 01071958737/DEVELOPER/dont_forget/ios/../ios/Flutter/App.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I just removed Google AdMob `admob_flutter` and tried another one `firebase_admob`. Maybe it happened I set something up wrong with `admob_flutter`. I'm not sure it's the right answer cuz it's been a while. but hope it helps.

Answer (score 242):

CocoaPods issue. Go to: `/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-AppName-frameworks.sh`

Replace in `*-frameworks.sh` files:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

With:

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

Comment: Yup can confirm this works after updating to MacOS Ventura 13.3 and Xcode 14.3, thanks!

Comment: Here the issue reported on cocoapods repo and possible PR: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808

Comment: Here is the exact path for **Flutter** projects: `/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh`

Comment: This issue fixes the error, however, now the version numbering is not following the version number in the Runner Identify. Is there a way to solve this, because you cannot upload new builds with the same version or build number?

Comment: @DennisAshford you can simply update the version number in XCode. And **important note**: you have to add the `-f` for each `archive` since it gets reset.

Comment: This issue appeared after upgrading to the latest xcode, this is the solution.

Comment: @Chris that didn't work at first, but after I updated the version number in Xcode, I rebuilt it without the `-f` tag, and then archived with the `-f` tag and that fixed the version numbering issue I was having.

Comment: Works! Came he after solving issue with Flutter iOS build for missing libarclite_iphoneos.a, after updating PodFile got this issue. And solution with -f helped (had to updated only 2 files with -f flag)

Comment: Building for flutter and during the process the file is reset. During `pod install`. So make sure to keep the file open and change it while building.

Comment: This solution really worked for me after several back and forths.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you! It works! Just remember: do not call pod install after this change (the file will reset again)

Comment: This is still a problem as of July 6, 2023 using Xcode 14.3.1. I will never not hate flutter.

Comment: can confirm this works, this has been eating my head over a day, thank you!! –

Comment: For any **Capacitor** users the path is /ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-Framework.sh

Answer (score 100):

> I tried delete derived data its not working.(But its the simplest way if some one can fix.)

Its clearly issue of cocoa-pods in Xcode 14.3 , rsync error.

**Solution :-**

- Right click on Pods and select 'Find in Selected Groups...'. Then  search for this line:

> source="$(readlink "${source}")"

- And replace the above line with this line:

> source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

[image]

[image: This is the file]

Comment: Hey dude, thanks a lot. I don't want to look like a newbie, but you answer it the only one where I figured out how to find this file to edit. U saved me!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.
Right-click on `Pods` and select `Find in Selected Groups...`

Comment: It works. How do you know that? :)

Comment: can confirm this works, this has been eating my head over a day, thank you!!

Comment: I did a "Find in Workspace" search and immediately found the file. Everything worked great.

Comment: WOW, this worked! I was able to build and run on device / simulator but could not ARCHIVE. BIG THANKS!

Answer (score 49):

There is an issue with Cocoapods now because **Xcode 14.3** is now using a relative path in its symlink for frameworks.

Either wait for release of Cocoapods version 1.12.1 or make this simple change in your **Pods-APPNAME-frameworks.sh** file:

full file path **`/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-APPNAME/Pods-APPNAME-frameworks.sh`**

**APPNAME** is your Application name

you need to SEARCH and REPLACE:

```
  if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
    echo "Symlinked..."
    source="$(readlink "${source}")"
  fi
```

with

```
  if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
    echo "Symlinked..."
    source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
  fi
```

Note that **-f** was added.

Comment: full file path /Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-APPNAME/Pods-APPNAME-frameworks.sh

Comment: This works, even with flutter

Comment: the hero we needed

Answer (score 22):

Ok y'all listen up.

This is caused by the new XCode 14.3 and Cocoapods needing an update. That update is now live so...

First update Cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then delete the Pods folder

```
cd <projectdir>
rm -rf Pods
```

Then run pod install

```
pod install
```

Happy days.

Comment: How was a question posted 3 years ago caused by Xcode 14.3?

Comment: Fixed with cocoa pods updated to 1.12.1

Comment: Hey, i'm using EAS build, so when i create the iOS build, during the `Run Fastlane` step it gives this error, how do we solve this as it is occurring on EAS build and not a local one, as in this case it is not upto us to update the cocoapods right?

Comment: I have installed the latest version of cocoapods (1.12.1), removed the pods folder and run pod install, but I'm still having the same issue

Comment: This works, thanks! XCode error messages are beyond useless lol

Answer (score 7):

Deleting derived data worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Fix is available on latest on latest version of cocoapods (at time of writing 1.12.1). Please run below commands you should to be good to go.

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

Error happens because of [Cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808). You can manually fix .sh scripts but after 'pod install' or other manipulations it could be cleared.

**Solution below is temporary** (soon new Cocoapods version will be released and problem should be fixed).
Who wants to work with updated Cocoapods (currenly in master) - [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828#issuecomment-1502034541);

Solution from Cocoapods github issues [page](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808) to change in Podfile:

```sh
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    shell_script_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-frameworks.sh"
    if File::exists?(shell_script_path)
      shell_script_input_lines = File.readlines(shell_script_path)
      shell_script_output_lines = shell_script_input_lines.map { |line| line.sub("source=\"$(readlink \"${source}\")\"", "source=\"$(readlink -f \"${source}\")\"") }
      File.open(shell_script_path, 'w') do |f|
        shell_script_output_lines.each do |line|
          f.write line
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am using fastlane and i was getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens with Xcode 14.3. Solution is just update the cocoapods to  1.12.1

you no need to do below manual podfile update

```
 if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
    echo "Symlinked..."
    source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
  fi
```

it will go away once you re do pod install.

**Solution :** https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting this error in EAS Build during the run fastlane step, I followed this solution and just updated cocoapods in the eas.json file to 1.12.1.

Using Expo 49.0.9 and react-native 0.72.4

```
    {
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "distribution": "store",
        "cocoapods": "1.12.1"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      },
      "channel": "production"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "cocoapods": "1.12.1"
      },
      "channel": "preview"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.34.1",
    "requireCommit": true
  }
}
```

[EAS build - rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76235741/eas-build-rsync-error-some-files-could-not-be-transferred-code-23-error)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal `pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all && pod install`

Worked for me