# flutter project failed to run on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have created a new project on mac using android studio and it still with default code I didn't change any thing and it works fine from android studio but when i tried to run it on xcode I am getting the following error

> building file list ... rsync: link_stat
> "/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/guide/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework"
> failed: No such file or directory (2)

as I understand from the error message it's an issue related to simulator but the simulator is working perfectly

Answer (score 4):

After updating to Xcode 14.3 I faced same issue.
For me this solution worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/75904326/21563124
Hope work for you as well.

You should make update to this file

```
/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
```

Replace in *-frameworks.sh files:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

with

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Derived data from Xcode causes these issues. Try cleaning Derived data folder in User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData , then go to Xcode and try Product > Clean Build Folder . Run `flutter clean && flutter pub get && cd ios && pod deintegrate && pod install` on project directory. Then run app on simulator. Let me know if it works for you.