# Cocoapods (AFNetworking) issue when archiving project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am trying to build a legacy Obj-C project, it's getting around 80% of progress and fails with the following error. I tried to reinstall pods, clean Derived Data, restart Xcode/computer.

```
`mkdir -p /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cghzlwxuhadyvrehqungfijxixti/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks

Symlinked...

rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" 

"../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework" "/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cghzlwxuhadyvrehqungfijxixti/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Frameworks"

building file list ... rsync: link_stat
 "/Users/myusername/myapp_ios/MyApp/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`
```

Comment: Have you tried adding AFNetworking directly as code instead of via CocoaPods? I have an older Obj-C project with AFNetworking and it still builds fine with Xcode 14.

Comment: @koen thanks but this will require updating the project significantly, would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533819/rsync-error-some-files-could-not-be-transferred-code-23-command-phasescriptex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using outdated Cocoapods version, please consider updating to the latest one.

As a temporary workaround, in your Pods-YourAppName-Frameworks.sh file you can change the following line:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

to:

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

Comment: Modifying .sh file worked like a charm, thanks