# "errSecInternalComponenet" Error on XCode when testing on an actual device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using ionic/angular framework in order to create code for iOS app.

- "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5"
- "@capacitor/core": "2.4.2"
- "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0"

My app is nothing but an ion-label with a text and 3 tabs screens (I was trying to replicate my error I had on my original project).
I git cloned my project into a VM of macOS Catalina v10.15.6
I executed the following commands as the documentation says:

```
ng build
ionic capacitor add ios
ionic capacitor copy ios 
ionic capacitor run ios
```

("copy ios" is not necessary, but I did it anw)

XCode v12.0.1 opens, I modify the team field and setting it to Personal Team

[image: Screenshot of Signing & Capabilities]

This is where the fun part starts.
When I run it on a simulator the build is successful, but when I try to test it on a physical device (iPhone SE, v14.0.1) the build fails and I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of XCode error message]

I did try this:

> Go to:
> Keychain Access -> Right-click on login -> Lock & unlock again
> Xcode -> Clean Xcode project ->Make build again

[from a stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Nothing changed.

I also tried to reset location & Privacy on my iphone (Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy). Still no change.

I kinda feel like it has something to do with the signing but it might be a capacitor problem?

Also, I had no problem with installing apps to my iphone through XCode, but I updated my iphone cause I had some problems with geolocations, and since then I'm having these errors

Desired behavior:
Successful build for my physical device and actually install it.

Please let me know if I need to update the info I have in this question.

Comment: this could be related to an invalid provisioning profile.. You should first add the device in your apple developer account and then generate a provisioning profile for this bundle id and include your test device as well..

Comment: @ChetanBansal According to this https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev40df0d9fa "If you use automatic signing, Xcode registers connected devices for you. Xcode Server can also be configured to register connected devices."
so does it mean that i don't need a provisioning profile?