# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode v12.0.1

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods, swift5, xcode12

I am using

Xcode v12.0.1
Cocoa pod v1.10.0.

This is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
plugin 'cocoapods-binary'

platform :ios, '8.0'

all_binary!

target 'Food' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Food

    

pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :binary => false
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', :binary => false
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'EasyTipView'
pod 'Hero'
pod 'SwiftLint'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'Koloda'
pod 'UIColor+FlatColors'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
pod 'JGProgressHUD'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'DTButtonMenuController'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'ActiveLabel', :binary => false
pod 'Intercom', '~> 5.4.1'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'GooglePlacesSearchController', :binary => false
pod 'GooglePlaces', :binary => false
pod 'GooglePlacePicker',:binary => false
pod 'GoogleMaps',:binary => false
pod 'AMPopTip'

end
```

All the dependencies are successfully installed and also Prebuilding process is also completed for all dependencies

[image]

[image]

Deployment target of my project and pod project is same -
[image]
[image]

Build phase:
[image]

I am getting this error when I am running app on iPhone 7 device.

[image]
[image]

What I tried :

1. I have removed derived data and cache and restart the Xcode and Mac.
2. I have also deleted all the pods podlock file, .workspace and then reinstall dependencies.
3. I have tried #1 and #2 many times.

After doing above points my issue is not resolved.

Comment: does this happening for all real devices? or Just iPhone 7(please mention it's OS details)?

Comment: Do you have custom .swiftlint.yml? If yes, please try removing the .swiftlint.yml file and follow step 2 from above.

Comment: Since the iOS Deployment target is: 13.0, it seems you should change `platform: ios, '8.0' to the 13.0`

Answer (score 1):

The pods deployment version maybe could be.
In my case when I've updated pods to the suggested target version my app starts to have a lot of warnings and errors.

But you can try with this post answers, it's a similar question.

[Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)