# How can i reinstall the react-native app in the simulator after deleting it?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I've just uninstalled my app in the simulator, and now I can't run it again using the react-native run-ios command. My simulator is open, but my app doesn't appear.

How can I reinstall my app to the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

After I close my previous `Metro` terminal, and run `react-native run-ios` command again, I am able to get it re-installed.

Comment: Another option is building from xcode ios project, this way it installs for sure.

Comment: Yicheng thanks for your response.

It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Close the metro bundle and then run `react-native run-ios` command.
If it still doesn't work, open Xcode and run the project on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned earlier in my comment, go to ios folder of the project, and open the .xcworkspace file or open the ios folder directly from xcode, and run the project on the simulator, this way it definitely will install your app.

Comment: Hi Oleksi thank you for your response. I did it but now I am getting a new error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. Any help on this?

Comment: @edonzeqiri try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code), since there might be several problems that can cause this error.