# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code [iOS/Flutter]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

I have a flutter application, which runs perfectly on Android.

When I'm trying to build and run the application for iOS I am getting the following error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I tried to delete the Podfile.lock and then do -->

> flutter clean

and then

> flutter build ios

yet I am getting the following error:

```
Building com.myname.example for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: XXXXXXXX
Running pod install...                                              3.3s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
Xcode build done.                                           39.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-01-26 19:45:02.637 xcodebuild[25920:52779202]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType
    from 00008006-000C82D4217B802E was NULL
    2021-01-26 19:45:02.741 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] DTDeviceKit:
    deviceType from 00008006-000C82D4217B802E was NULL
    2021-01-26 19:45:02.743 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] DTDeviceKit:
    deviceType from 00008006-000C82D4217B802E was NULL
    2021-01-26 19:45:02.746 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] DTDeviceKit:
    deviceType from 00008006-000C82D4217B802E was NULL
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.134 xcodebuild[25920:52779203]  iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> unable to mount developer disk image, (Error
    Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "The current device configuration is
    unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not
    supported by Xcode 11.7." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current
    device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3
    (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.,
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=To run on this device, please update to a
    version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac
    App Store or the Apple Developer website., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927,
    DeviceType=iPhone12,1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd96b7db300 {Error
    Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 "Unable to locate
    ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66"
    UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66, DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}}}) {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "The current device configuration is
        unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not
        supported by Xcode 11.7.";
        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "To run on this device, please update to
        a version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from
        the Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website.";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error
        Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 \"Unable to locate
        ideal DDI for platform:
        <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0
        x7fd9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPho
        neOS.platform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66\"
        UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to locate ideal DDI for
        platform:
        <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0
        x7fd9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPho
        neOS.platform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66,
        DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}";
    }
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.135 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> -- An error occurred whilst preparing device for
    development -- The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone
    11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.135 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> == Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.135 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked
    by passcode.
    Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
    Code: 5
    Failure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
    User Info: {
        DVTDeviceDescription = "\Ud83d\Udcf1<DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30),
        Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66), 00008030-001145D9026B802E>";
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.135 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect: The
    current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS
    14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.135 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect: The
    current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS
    14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:03.135 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.452 xcodebuild[25920:52779195]  iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> unable to mount developer disk image, (Error
    Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "The current device configuration is
    unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not
    supported by Xcode 11.7." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current
    device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3
    (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.,
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=To run on this device, please update to a
    version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac
    App Store or the Apple Developer website., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927,
    DeviceType=iPhone12,1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd96a1d2f60 {Error
    Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 "Unable to locate
    ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66"
    UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66, DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}}}) {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "The current device configuration is
        unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not
        supported by Xcode 11.7.";
        NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "To run on this device, please update to
        a version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from
        the Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website.";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error
        Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 \"Unable to locate
        ideal DDI for platform:
        <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0
        x7fd9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPho
        neOS.platform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66\"
        UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to locate ideal DDI for
        platform:
        <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0
        x7fd9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPho
        neOS.platform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66,
        DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}";
    }
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.452 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> -- An error occurred whilst preparing device for
    development -- The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone
    11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.452 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> == Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.453 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked
    by passcode.
    Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
    Code: 5
    Failure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
    User Info: {
        DVTDeviceDescription = "\Ud83d\Udcf1<DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30),
        Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66), 00008030-001145D9026B802E>";
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.453 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect: The
    current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS
    14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.453 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect: The
    current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS
    14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.453 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect: The
    current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS
    14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.453 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect: The
    current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS
    14.3 (18C66), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
    Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
    Code: 601
    Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of
    Xcode that supports iOS 14.3. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store
    or the Apple Developer website.
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
        DeviceType = "iPhone12,1";
    }
    --
    Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd965513860:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd
    9655135e0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.pla
    tform'>>, version: 14.3, build: 18C66
    Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
    Code: 2
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    }
    --
    2021-01-26 19:45:04.453 xcodebuild[25920:52778965] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2021-01-26 19:45:11.411 xcodebuild[25920:52779202]  iPhoneSupport:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage (Error
    Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "The current device configuration is
    unsupported. This Apple Watch is running watchOS 7.2 (18S563), which is not
    supported by Xcode 11.7." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current
    device configuration is unsupported. This Apple Watch is running watchOS 7.2
    (18S563), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.,
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=To run on this device, please update to a
    version of Xcode that supports watchOS 7.2. You can download Xcode from the
    Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927,
    DeviceType=Watch5,9, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd96acd33b0 {Error
    Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 "Unable to locate
    ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd9655166d0:'com.apple.platform.watchos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd9
    65516650:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platf
    orm'>>, version: 7.2, build: 18S563" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable
    to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd9655166d0:'com.apple.platform.watchos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd9
    65516650:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platf
    orm'>>, version: 7.2, build: 18S563, DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}}})
    2021-01-26 19:45:13.929 xcodebuild[25920:52779033]  iPhoneSupport:
    <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fd96a532d30), Somdip's iPhone 11, iPhone, 14.3 (18C66),
    00008030-001145D9026B802E> unable to mount DeveloperDiskImage (Error
    Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "The current device configuration is
    unsupported. This Apple Watch is running watchOS 7.2 (18S563), which is not
    supported by Xcode 11.7." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current
    device configuration is unsupported. This Apple Watch is running watchOS 7.2
    (18S563), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.,
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=To run on this device, please update to a
    version of Xcode that supports watchOS 7.2. You can download Xcode from the
    Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927,
    DeviceType=Watch5,9, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd967427c30 {Error
    Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 "Unable to locate
    ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd9655166d0:'com.apple.platform.watchos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd9
    65516650:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platf
    orm'>>, version: 7.2, build: 18S563" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable
    to locate ideal DDI for platform:
    <DVTPlatform:0x7fd9655166d0:'com.apple.platform.watchos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd9
    65516650:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platf
    orm'>>, version: 7.2, build: 18S563, DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}}})
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/somdipdey/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibrat
    ion-1.5.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:6:4: warning: 'SwiftVibrationPlugin'
    is only available on iOS 13.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
      [SwiftVibrationPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from
    /Users/somdipdey/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibrat
    ion-1.5.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:2:
    /Users/somdipdey/flutter_projects/nosh_app_new_dev/nosh_app/nosh/build/ios/R
    elease-iphoneos/vibration/vibration.framework/Headers/vibration-Swift.h:437:
    12: note: 'SwiftVibrationPlugin' has been marked as being introduced in iOS
    13.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
    @interface SwiftVibrationPlugin : NSObject <FlutterPlugin>
               ^
    /Users/somdipdey/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibrat
    ion-1.5.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m:6:4: note: enclose
    'SwiftVibrationPlugin' in an @available check to silence this warning
      [SwiftVibrationPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further
    output
    CompileC
    /Users/somdipdey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwsspisdjxqqorgn
    buuuebjmrwvt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/vibrati
    on.build/Objects-normal/arm64/VibrationPlugin.o
    /Users/somdipdey/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/vibrat
    ion-1.5.0/ios/Classes/VibrationPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
    com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

    Compiler message:
    lib/helpers/sourceAndImageFetcherDialog.dart:71:11: Error: No named
    parameter with the name 'activeWidgetColor'.
              activeWidgetColor: Color(0xff0000ff),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_cropp
    er-1.3.1/lib/src/options.dart:115:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the
    arguments don't match.
      const AndroidUiSettings(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    lib/helpers/sourceAndImageFetcherDialog.dart:90:13: Error: No named
    parameter with the name 'activeWidgetColor'.
                activeWidgetColor: Color(0xff0000ff),
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_cropp
    er-1.3.1/lib/src/options.dart:115:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the
    arguments don't match.
      const AndroidUiSettings(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation:
    null
    build failed.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.
```

I also tried the solutions here: [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code) but with no luck!

How to resolve this issue and run the app on the iPhone?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. "The current device configuration is
        unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 14.3 (18C66), which is not
        supported by Xcode 11.7."

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem: Update Xcode to 12.4 and update iOS on your iPhone to 14.4. The .X version of the Xcode should match the .X version of iOS on your iPhone. Which means that in this case Y.4 of Xcode version needs to match Y.4 version of the iOS on your iPhone.