# Command PhaseScriptExecution Failed with nonzero exit

Tags: flutter, command, upgrade, exit, xcode12

Here is the error, when I run it in the xCode 12.

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/simonwong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-frcmcdsmkzueqwaafgkobyjnbawp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
cd /Users/simonwong/aigogo/ios
export ACTION\=build
export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED\=YES
export ALTERNATE_GROUP\=staff
export ALTERNATE_MODE\=u+w,go-w,a+rX
export ALTERNATE_OWNER\=simonwong
export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES\=YES
export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS\=NO
export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS\=NO
export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Developer
export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR\=/AppleInternal
export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Documentation
export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Library
export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS\=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY\=NO
export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES\=NO
export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS\=NO
export ARCHS\=x86_64
export ARCHS_STANDARD\=arm64\ x86_64\ i386
export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT\=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT\=i386
export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT\=arm64\ x86_64
export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT\=arm64\ x86_64\ i386
export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS\=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME\=AppIcon
export ASSETCATALOG_FILTER_FOR_DEVICE_MODEL\=iPhone10,4
export ASSETCATALOG_FILTER_FOR_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\=14.4
export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS\=appletvos\ appletvsimulator\ iphoneos\ iphonesimulator\ macosx\ watchos\ watchsimulator


../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Info: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.

class Utf8 extends Struct {
  ^

../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Info: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.

class Utf16 extends Struct {
  ^

../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Info: Support for using non-constant type arguments 'T' in this FFI API is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Rewrite the code to ensure that type arguments are compile time constants referring to a valid native type.

final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                            ^
```

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but restarting the computer solved my problem.