# M1 MacBook Pro Flutter App : Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: flutter, arm64, apple-m1

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

When running the Flutter project from VS Code it works fine. When trying to run it from Xcode getting this error.

I have done everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

As this is a Flutter project the Script is:

```
/Users/aby/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh
```

Comment: What is the script being executed?

Comment: Same issue for here, Looking for a solution

Answer (score 4):

I've come across the same issue, and I noticed that when running via vscode, I hit no issues. Then I tried running the app from within Xcode but in Rosetta mode (simulator running as x86, as running via vscode does). This seemed to work.

To do so, I added this to my Podfile (to make pods compile in x86 mode)

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

  # This is to remove arm64 from the available archs:
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

You must manually do this on the EXCLUDED_ARCHS of your project as well. After that, it all worked out fine. I *think* that Flutter is still not running on native M1 Macs.