# New project on React Native 0.64.2 is not building via Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**New clear project is not running on physical device via Xcode.**

But `npx react-native run-ios` works perfect. issue is only with Xcode when trying to build and test in physical device.

*Physical device: iPhone 8 Plus iOS 14.6*

Getting this error:
cp: /Users/uktamhamidov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SQRE-arjlqbohgbkkananywponwudfhts/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Axm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed pod file inside ios folder

If you are already installed delete the podfile.lock and Pods folder and then install pods again.

`cd ios && pod install`

Then when it's done go back to your main folder and run

yarn run ios

If that doesn't work, [check out the solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iOS 14.6 issue, once I updated to it my project is failing to build with the same error, Xcode actually doesn't even have support for 14.6 according to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`