# FBReactNativeSpec, PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

I have been having issues trying to create an IOS build of a react native application. Originally I made this on windows with an android emulator. Then I tried to build the react native code on mac with xcode but I can't get past this error.

I have tried a couple things like reinstalling node and unsetting the PREFIX variable in the find-node script but I have not gotten any further

When inspecting the error it says:

- FBReactNativeSpec - Uncategorized - PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

int he details there is another error that says:

- bash: mobile/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../Libraries: No such file or directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue on my MacBook Pro with M1 chip.
I managed to get rid of the FBReactNativeSpec error by editing the Project settings.

Try the following:

1. In Xcode select your app's project and then select the target.
2. In Terminal enter the following command to find out the path of your node installation:

`which node`

This should give you a path. Something like:

**/Users/thomashuber/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node**

3. Copy this path.
4. In Xcode with the target selected click on **Build Phases** and open **Bundle React Native code and images**
5. Replace `NODE_BINARY=node`. Instead of node enter the path that you have copied so that it is something like this `NODE_BINARY=/Users/thomashuber/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node`

[image: Replacing node with node path]

Answer (score -1):

The Above solution works but always keep in mind that.

> which node

First run this command. In my case my path of Node was different. So only paste the path which given by the **"which node"** command

Answer (score -1):

[image]
[image]

i also had similar issue, same as `es1` i change the config from xcode `node_binary` also on target `FBReactNativeSpec` build phase (if not available yet you can add it to your target).
also refer to this link:

- [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)
- [Xcode 14: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760753/xcode-14-0-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)
- https://reactnative.dev/docs/new-architecture-troubleshooting
- [React Native - FBReactNativeSpec Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096289/react-native-fbreactnativespec-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonz)