# PhaseScriptExecution failed when trying to run React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am a newcomer when it comes to React Native. However, when I tried to follow the steps that React Native provided: [Environment Setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) (I chose to use React Native CLI, Mac and iOS). Everything went fine until I tried to run the command

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

This is the error log that I received in the Terminal:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/phillip/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-csoqwegnbwhthjczvzcjwqasamef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00018F30.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I am using a MacBook Air with

M1 chip
MacOS Monterey
Xcode Version 14.2
node v19.6.0
Metro v0.73.7

I searched for a bunch of solutions, including the node versions, nvm, uninstalling `build` folder and use `pod install`, commenting `post_install` function inside Podfile file, but nothing works so far. I am using Node v19.6.0 and this is my `which node` output: `/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.0/bin/node`.

I also tried solutions from this reference: [React Native - FBReactNativeSpec Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096289/react-native-fbreactnativespec-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonz) but nothing has worked

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.