# When I try to run the project on a physical device I get an error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I try to run the project on a physical device I get an error
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

- Note, this is a new project

```
Node found at: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
+ DEST=/Users/yousef/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/runOnPhysicalDevice-aymcfikqwaiecvdkkyyvriqobkoc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/runOnPhysicalDevice.app
+ [[ ! -n '' ]]
+ [[ Debug = *Debug* ]]
+ [[ ! iphoneos == *simulator ]]
+ for num in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
++ ipconfig getifaddr en0
+ IP=
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the ios project on the Xcode:

```
cd ios => open projectName.xcworkspace
```

this will open the project on Xcode, try to build the project with Xcode, this will allow you to find where the error is located.

If any error appears, try to solve it and run the project on the physical device.

If an error persists, please share it here, so someone can help.

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 0):

This is the error from xCode

@Rodrigo Dias

[image]

Comment: take a look at this post: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096289/react-native-fbreactnativespec-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonz

There is a valid solution, maybe this works to you as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same error (only when running on physical device), I still doesn't found the solution since hours...