# React native app can run on ios simulator but not on physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have built and app using React Native cli, works well on Android device, Android emulator and iOS simulator. However whenever I try to debug using ios device, the app won't build.
I'm using MacBook Pro M1
React Native 0.69.7
XCode 14.3
node version 19.7.0

The device I'm using is iPhone XS, iOS 16.3.1

I used the command:
`yarn react-native run-ios --device`
through react native terminal in gives the error message:

```
sr/bin/codesign --force --sign 1234567890123467890  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/<myusernamehere>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<appName>-9876543210987654321/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/<appName>.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework'

/Users/<myusernamehere>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<appName>-98765432109876543210/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/<appName>.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework: errSecInternalComponent

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/<myusernamehere>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<appName-randomStringabcdefgh>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/<appName>.build/Debug-iphoneos/<appName>.build/Script-12345678901234567890.sh (in target '<appName>' from project '<appName>')

2023-04-03 15:54:23.443 xcodebuild[99293:531580] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

trying to run it from xcode (after assigning a physical device in Xcode) gives the error
`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

I followed the instruction here
https://reactnative.dev/docs/new-architecture-troubleshooting#xcode-build-issues
I found the log file mentioned but it didn't give me much information of what to fix.

I then happen to come across this:  [FBReactNativeSpec, PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199396/fbreactnativespec-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

when I did `which node`
it gives me : /opt/homebrew/bin/node

I tried to follow the instruction and I did change the contents in my `.xcode.env` file to:
`export NODE_BINARY='/opt/homebrew/bin/node'`
but it doesn't really help.

Could someone point out what I did wrong and why I could build and run the app successfully in the simulator, but not on iOs device.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is related to [Xcode 14.3 fix: Pass the -f option when resolving the path to the symlinked source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828).  Until this ship fixes, in the file

```
ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
```

you can change `source="$(readlink "${source}")"`
to `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`.