# Newly created flutter app fails to build iOS

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am using flutter to build an App for IOS and I manage to create the project smoothly. Before I put any code or dependencies I run  `flutter build apk` and this builds the apk successfully. I then run  `flutter build ios` and I get this error **Failed to package... Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**.

I have run flutter doctor and I have no issues. I am running latest flutter version Channel stable, 2.8.0. Latest android studio version 2020.3(Arctic Fox). Latest Xcode 13.1 Release. And Latest MacOs Monterey 12.0.1.

I have tried all solutions I could google but nothing works. Why would it not run when i have not even added any of my code. Just a clean project getting stuck.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanx

Comment: hi, perhaps the build tools need to be updated?

Comment: I thought build tools are for android and that builds well. My issue is with the iOS. How do you update these build tools. Am willing to try anything

Comment: Nope, @jspcal my build tools are fine.

Comment: update cocoapods

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: @DipakPrajapati I have update cocoapods but still same error. Help appreciated

Comment: @RakeshSaini Tried everything on that link in vain. Still stuck. Help