# command phasescriptexecution failed with a nonzero exit code ios during archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift5

I am facing this issue for the last two days and I am not able to resolve it till now. I have tried everything on google and nothing works. This only happens when I create an archive but runs fine on the simulator. Can somebody help me with this?

Specifications :
MacBook Pro 2021 with macOS Monterey Apple M1 Pro chip
XCode: 13.2.1

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: I tried it but it was not helpful and my lock and unlock login keychain option is disabled as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you are using some third-party libraries make sure that all is configured perfectly.
Add dependencies in header search paths.