# Flutter: Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when running on IOS

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

my project a few days ago was running fine but today when i ran it, an error occurred

First I run the project normally, then I get an error message **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code** like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i32Ll.png)

i research and follow : [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

I check to **For install build only** and rebuild [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TihZa.png)

but i got new err **'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found**

I'm following this link: [error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when flutter run on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973346/error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-when-flutter-run-on-ios/64993852#64993852)
but no ways work for me.

my flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-VN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  pod 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery', :git => 'https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
              '$(inherited)',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
              # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
              # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
               'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
               'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
              # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
              # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
               'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

              ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
              # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
               'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
               'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
              # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
              # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

              ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
              # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1'
            ]
      end
  end
end
```

when i run with `flutter run` the error is

```
ailed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[2422]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1d9fbf458) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1047904f8).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[2422]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1d9fbf4a8) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x104790548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[2422]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1d9fbf4f8) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x104790598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[2422]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1d9fbf548) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1047905e8). One of the
    two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[2422]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1d9fbf598) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104790638). One
    of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[2422]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1d9fbf5e8) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x104790688). One of
    the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    2022-08-08 15:50:31.871 xcodebuild[2422:318480] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-08-08 15:50:31.871 xcodebuild[2422:318480] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/dr/g3m_83x133sgqld2s81hkcbm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.BrO096/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirz0bX8m/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included from /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
    #import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
            ^
    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header
    '/Users/anhdinhhoangquang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hftipncmgtfzwkejzigesjjczlmu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2VRBUORSX1OJB-clang_1S85MWRYG1P34.pch' for bridging header
    '/Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: note: in file included from /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:
    #import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
            ^
    2 errors generated.
    error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target
    'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target
    'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target
    'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target
    'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/dr/g3m_83x133sgqld2s81hkcbm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.BrO096/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirz0bX8m/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8


Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/anhdinhhoangquang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hftipncmgtfzwkejzigesjjczlmu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_2VRBUORSX1OJB-clang_1S85MWRYG1P34.pch' for bridging header
'/Users/anhdinhhoangquang/cloudv/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
```

i'm also built by Xcode
and get err like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVGbB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do this:

1. Backup Runner folder
2. Delete the `ios` folder
   3.Go to a terminal and execute `flutter create .` in the flutter project folder
3. Paste your Runner folder back into the `ios` folder
4. `pod deintegrate` in the `ios` folder
5. `pod install` also in the `ios` folder
6. `flutter clean` in the flutter project folder
7. `flutter pub get`
8. `flutter run`

Please note that if you use firebase you need to re-insert the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file

Comment: i dont see flutter.framework on my directory lol. it maybe cause. i'll try thank you

Comment: i  uncheck to **For install builds only** in **Build Phases**
it throw message **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

Comment: in build phases: run script and thin binary, select: `run script only when installing`

Comment: i only see **For install builds only** in my Xcode

Comment: it still not working :(

Comment: Why you uncheck `install builds only`

Comment: kindly try to ask another question as you are facing another issue

Comment: first i ran it throw without **For install builds only** it throw **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**. i research and find away by check it. but throw **'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found**

Comment: update your question with the error

Comment: which error you are facing now? `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.` or `Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`

Comment: ```Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found``` i try your ways but still not working :(.
i cant see flutter.framework in my **ios/Flutter** directory

Comment: just run `pod install`

Comment: i did that many time :(. because i using M1. t run step by step 
```arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update``` and ```arch -x86_64 pod install```

Comment: Have you updated flutter version?

Comment: i'm in stable channel and my flutter version is 3.0.5

Comment: check update answer

Comment: i will try now and response to you

Comment: i'm updating Xcode to lastest version. it will take time. i will response to you asap

Comment: still not working :((

Comment: how magic, after do that 3 times it work . thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help you . kindly upvote my answer.

Comment: new account cant vote :(

Answer (score 2):

open iOS folder Podfile and uncomment platform line and change it to 11

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

And open ios folder in terminal and run

`pod install`

And open iOS project in xcode and make sure your pod deployment target change to 11

[image]

Comment: it's not working :(