# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. During build Flutter Project in Xcode 13.4

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

*I have tried almost all command to flutter clean, flutter pub get and i have also tried to degrade flutter version but did not worked.*

*I have tried almost all stack solution but i am unable to resolve this, is any one please look up it and please help me.*

**Please see The Error Log below**

```
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
 \'@executable_path/Frameworks\'\ \'@loader_path/Frameworks\'\ @executable_path/Frameworks
        export LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
        export LEX\=lex
        export LIBRARY_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/Library/DriverExtensions
        export LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE\=YES
        export LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX\=-l
        export LIBRARY_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/Library/Extensions
        export LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift
        export LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES\=NO
        export LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_arm64\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.LinkFileList
        export LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES\=YES
        export LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_OS_VERSION\=ios9.0
        export LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_VENDOR\=apple
        export LOCALIZATION_EXPORT_SUPPORTED\=YES
        export LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/en.lproj
        export LOCALIZED_STRING_MACRO_NAMES\=NSLocalizedString\ CFCopyLocalizedString
        export LOCALIZED_STRING_SWIFTUI_SUPPORT\=YES
        export LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR\=/Applications/Utilities
        export LOCAL_APPS_DIR\=/Applications
        export LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Library/Developer
        export LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR\=/Library
        export LOCROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/SALK/salk_v3_flutter/ios
        export LOCSYMROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/SALK/salk_v3_flutter/ios
        export MACH_O_TYPE\=mh_execute
        export MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=21F79
        export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL\=120400
        export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR\=120000
        export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR\=120400
        export METAL_LIBRARY_FILE_BASE\=default
        export METAL_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app
        export MODULES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/Modules
        export MODULE_CACHE_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
        export MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO\=YES
        export NATIVE_ARCH\=arm64
        export NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT\=arm
        export NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT\=arm64
        export NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL\=arm64
        export NO_COMMON\=YES
        export OBJECT_FILE_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects
        export OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal
        export OBJROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex
        export ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH\=YES
        export OS\=MACOS
        export OSAC\=/usr/bin/osacompile
        export OTHER_LDFLAGS\=\ -ObjC\ -l\"c++\"\ -l\"sqlite3\"\ -l\"z\"\ -framework\ \"AVFoundation\"\ -framework\ \"AVKit\"\ -framework\ \"CoreTelephony\"\ -framework\ \"DKImagePickerController\"\ -framework\ \"DKPhotoGallery\"\ -framework\ \"FBLPromises\"\ -framework\ \"FMDB\"\ -framework\ \"FirebaseCore\"\ -framework\ \"FirebaseCoreDiagnostics\"\ -framework\ \"FirebaseCrashlytics\"\ -framework\ \"FirebaseInstallations\"\ -framework\ \"FirebaseMessaging\"\ -framework\ \"Foundation\"\ -framework\ \"GoogleDataTransport\"\ -framework\ \"GoogleUtilities\"\ -framework\ \"ImageIO\"\ -framework\ \"Mantle\"\ -framework\ \"OrderedSet\"\ -framework\ \"Photos\"\ -framework\ \"SDWebImage\"\ -framework\ \"SDWebImageWebPCoder\"\ -framework\ \"Security\"\ -framework\ \"SwiftyGif\"\ -framework\ \"SystemConfiguration\"\ -framework\ \"UIKit\"\ -framework\ \"activity_recognition_flutter\"\ -framework\ \"device_info_plus\"\ -framework\ \"file_picker\"\ -framework\ \"firebase_core\"\ -framework\ \"firebase_crashlytics\"\ -framework\ \"firebase_messaging\"\ -framework\ \"flutter_image_compress\"\ -framework\ \"flutter_inappwebview\"\ -framework\ \"flutter_local_notifications\"\ -framework\ \"flutter_native_timezone\"\ -framework\ \"geocoder\"\ -framework\ \"geolocator_apple\"\ -framework\ \"health\"\ -framework\ \"image_picker_ios\"\ -framework\ \"libwebp\"\ -framework\ \"nanopb\"\ -framework\ \"package_info\"\ -framework\ \"path_provider_ios\"\ -framework\ \"shared_preferences_ios\"\ -framework\ \"sqflite\"\ -framework\ \"step_counter\"\ -framework\ \"webview_flutter\"\ -weak_framework\ \"UserNotifications\"
        export OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS\=\ -D\ COCOAPODS
        export PACKAGE_CONFIG\=.dart_tool/package_config.json
        export PACKAGE_TYPE\=com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application
        export PASCAL_STRINGS\=YES
        export PATH\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
        exportPROJECT_FILE_PATH\=/Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/SALK/salk_v3_flutter/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
        export PROJECT_NAME\=Runner
        export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build
        export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex
        export PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED\=YES
        export PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/Headers
        export RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS\=YES
        export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES\=YES
        export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export RESOURCE_RULES_REQUIRED\=YES
        export REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/ResourceManagerResources
        export REZ_OBJECTS_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
        export REZ_SEARCH_PATHS\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos\ 
        export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES\=NO
        export SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/Scripts
        export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT\=0
        export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT\=0
        export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT\=0
        export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT\=0
        export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
        export SDK_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
        export SDK_DIR_iphoneos\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
        export SDK_DIR_iphoneos15_5\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk
        export SDK_NAME\=iphoneos15.5
        export SDK_NAMES\=iphoneos15.5
        export SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=19F64
        export SDK_VERSION\=15.5
        export SDK_VERSION_ACTUAL\=150500
        export SDK_VERSION_MAJOR\=150000
        export SDK_VERSION_MINOR\=150500
        export SED\=/usr/bin/sed
        export SEPARATE_STRIP\=NO
        export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT\=NO
        export SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP\=YES
        export SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP\=NO
        export SHALLOW_BUNDLE\=YES
        export SHALLOW_BUNDLE_TRIPLE\=ios
        export SHALLOW_BUNDLE_ios_macabi\=NO
        export SHALLOW_BUNDLE_macos\=NO
        export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DerivedSources
        export SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/SharedFrameworks
        export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders
        export SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/SharedSupport
        export SKIP_INSTALL\=NO
        export SOURCE_ROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/SALK/salk_v3_flutter/ios
        export SRCROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/SALK/salk_v3_flutter/ios
        export STRINGSDATA_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/undefined_arch
        export STRINGSDATA_ROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build
        export STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME\=YES
        export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING\=binary
        export STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES\=YES
        export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT\=NO
        export STRIP_STYLE\=all
        export STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS\=YES
        export SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES\=1,2
        export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS\=iphoneos\ iphonesimulator
        export SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST\=NO
        export SUPPORTS_MAC_DESIGNED_FOR_IPHONE_IPAD\=YES
        export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API\=NO
        export SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS\=NO
        export SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER\=Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
        export SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL\=-Onone
        export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX\=ios
        export SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE_PATH_normal_arm64\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.SwiftFileList
        export SWIFT_VERSION\=5.0
        export SYMROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Products
        export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR\=/Applications/Utilities
        export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR\=/Applications
        export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR\=/System/Library/CoreServices
        export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR\=/Applications/Extras
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built\ Examples
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics\ Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java\ Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance\ Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/releasenotes
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/documentation/DeveloperTools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
        export SYSTEM_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
        export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR\=/Library/Documentation
        export SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/SystemExtensions
        export SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS_FOLDER_PATH_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=Runner.app/Library/SystemExtensions
        export SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS_FOLDER_PATH_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_YES\=Runner.app/SystemExtensions
        export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/Extensions
        export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR\=/System/Library
        export TAPI_ENABLE_PROJECT_HEADERS\=NO
        export TAPI_VERIFY_MODE\=ErrorsOnly
        export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY\=1,2
        export TARGETNAME\=Runner
        export TARGET_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
        export TARGET_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER\=13be6e6ab44318d82b11b70609333ee2910902ec
        export TARGET_DEVICE_MODEL\=iPhone7,2
        export TARGET_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\=12.5.5
        export TARGET_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\=iphoneos
        export TARGET_NAME\=Runner
        export TARGET_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build
        export TEMP_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build
        export TEMP_FILES_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build
        export TEMP_FILE_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build
        export TEMP_ROOT\=/Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex
        export TEST_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS\=\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
        export TEST_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS\=\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib
        export TOOLCHAINS\=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
        export TOOLCHAIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
        export TRACK_WIDGET_CREATION\=false
        export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES\=NO
        export TREE_SHAKE_ICONS\=false
        export TeamIdentifierPrefix\=RRGTVR3V7Y.
        export UID\=501
        export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app
        export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=Runner.app/Resources
        export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_YES\=Runner.app
        export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT\=NO
        export USER\=andolasoft
        export USER_APPS_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Applications
        export USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS\=\ /Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/SALK/salk_v3_flutter/ios/libwebp/src
        export USER_LIBRARY_DIR\=/Users/andolasoft/Library
        export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC\=YES
        export USE_HEADERMAP\=YES
        export USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS\=NO
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES\=YES
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_CLANG\=YES
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_LD\=YES
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_TAPI\=YES
        export USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES\=YES
        export VALIDATE_DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS\=YES_ERROR
        export VALIDATE_PRODUCT\=NO
        export VALIDATE_WORKSPACE\=YES_ERROR
        export VALID_ARCHS\=arm64\ arm64e\ armv7\ armv7s
        export VERBOSE_PBXCP\=NO
        export VERSIONING_SYSTEM\=apple-generic
        export VERSIONPLIST_PATH\=Runner.app/version.plist
        export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER\=andolasoft
        export VERSION_INFO_FILE\=Runner_vers.c
        export VERSION_INFO_STRING\=\"@\(\#\)PROGRAM:Runner\ \ PROJECT:Runner-16.9.67\"
        export WRAPPER_EXTENSION\=app
        export WRAPPER_NAME\=Runner.app
        export WRAPPER_SUFFIX\=.app
        export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES\=NO
        export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
        export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=13F17a
        export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL\=1340
        export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR\=1300
        export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR\=1340
        export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/XPCServices
        export YACC\=yacc
        export _WRAPPER_CONTENTS_DIR_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=/Contents
        export _WRAPPER_PARENT_PATH_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=/..
        export _WRAPPER_RESOURCES_DIR_SHALLOW_BUNDLE_NO\=/Resources
        export __CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED_appletvos\=NO
        export __CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED_iphoneos\=NO
        export __CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED_watchos\=NO
        export arch\=undefined_arch
        export variant\=normal
        /bin/sh -c /Users/andolasoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-epiuplgxnynbuegddnnbonwlbhsh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh
                       ^
    ../../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/youtube_player_flutter-8.0.0/lib/src/widgets/youtube_player_builder.dart:51:43: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
     - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        final physicalSize = SchedulerBinding.instance?.window.physicalSize;
                                              ^
    Failed to package /Users/andolasoft/Desktop/Development/PROJECT/projectname.
    **Cmmand PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**
```

Error Found While Running Flutter Project In Xcode

[image]

Comment: Please share errors and stack traces as text rather than screenshots. This will help to understand why: [ask]

Comment: @Markus i have added some error logs please look once on it.

Comment: Have you also tried this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)